# CTAD with aggregate initialization of nested templated base class

Tags: c++, c++20, ctad

Due to the aggregate initialization rules, I would expect to be able to initialize `d::q` by passing an object of its direct base class. However, Clang and MSVC seem to reject this code.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template<typename> struct s {};
template<typename> struct b {
    template<typename T>
    struct p : s<T> {};
};
template<typename U>
struct d : b<U> {
    template<typename T>
    using t = b<U>::template p<T>;
    template<typename T>
    struct q : t<T> {};
    static constexpr auto v = q{t<U>{}};
};
static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(d<int>::v), d<int>::q<int> const>);
```

Shouldn't there be some kind of implicit deduction guide generated for `d::q` that would allow for the construction of `q{t<U>{}}`? What does the C++20 standard has to say about this? What specific mechanism should kick into action here?

<s>Also, what would be a possible workaround for this issue (constructing `d::q` with the use of CTAD) that makes the code compile on the latest stable version of all 3 compilers (Clang, GCC, MSVC) without making things overly convoluted? Providing a user-defined deduction guide for `d::q` seems to work for MSVC but Clang complains about a `non-deducible template parameter`.</s>

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zvaosqGeo)

---

Clang's error message:

```cpp
<source>:15:31: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of
template arguments of 'q'
   15 |     static constexpr auto v = q{t<U>{}};
      |                               ^
<source>:17:37: note: in instantiation of template class 'd<int>' requested here
   17 | static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(d<int>::v), d<int>::q<int> const>);
      |                                     ^
<source>:14:12: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'q' against 'p'
   14 |     struct q : t<T> {};
      |            ^
<source>:14:12: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 0 arguments,
but 1 was provided
<source>:17:62: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
   17 | static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(d<int>::v), d<int>::q<int> const>);
      |                                                           ~~~^
<source>:17:64: error: expected expression
   17 | static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(d<int>::v), d<int>::q<int> const>);
      |
```

MSVC's error message:

```cpp
<source>(15): error C2641: cannot deduce template arguments for 'd<int>::q'
<source>(15): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
<source>(17): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'd<int>' being
compiled
<source>(15): error C2780: 'd<U>::q<T> d<int>::q(void)': expects 0 arguments -
1 provided
<source>(14): note: see declaration of 'd<int>::q'
<source>(15): error C2784: 'd<U>::q<T> d<int>::q(d<U>::q<T>)': could not deduce
template argument for 'd<U>::q<T>' from 'b<U>::p<U>'
        with
        [
            U=int
        ]
<source>(14): note: see declaration of 'd<int>::q'
<source>(15): error C2783: 'd<U>::q<T> d<int>::q(b<<unnamed-symbol>>::p<T>)':
could not deduce template argument for 'T'
<source>(14): note: see declaration of 'd<int>::q'
<source>(15): error C2119: 'v': the type for 'auto' cannot be deduced from an
empty initializer
<source>(17): error C2607: static assertion failed
<source>(17): note: the concept 'std::same_as<const int,const d<int>::q<int>>'
evaluated to false
C:/data/msvc/14.38.33133/include\concepts(35): note: 'const int'
and 'const d<int>::q<int>' are different types
```

Comment: One workaround is to use default parameter for `q` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77973884/12002570). Other workaround is to explicitly pass `U` but that will make CTAD not work.

Comment: Why are you vandalising your post be removing the part where you asked about a workaround? This makes the already posted answer invalid. And it wastes people's time. If someone know if it is well-formed or not they can still answer the question(without any need to remove the workaround part)

Comment: @user12002570 Because, unfortunately, I've realized it that the core gist of the problem probably isn't solvable anyway. So, others will focus mainly on having a different approach to the whole problem, which is not what I'm looking. I agree that I've kinda butchered this question by not spelling out the requirements properly.

Answer (score 0):

> what would be a possible workaround for this issue that **makes the code compile on all 3 compilers** (Clang, GCC, MSVC) **without making things overly convoluted?**

You can default the template parameter for `q` as shown below:

```
//------------------vvv---->use default
template<typename T = U>
struct q : t<T> {};
```

Now also the program works for all compilers.

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qGErdvq4o)

Comment: Yes, I had forgotton to mention this, but having to use CTAD for `d::q`'s construction is one of the requirements. Also, this answer does not address the main question in my post.

Comment: @303 I see, that was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @303 I've added another method of making the program work with all compilers. In particular, you can default the template parameter of `q`. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qGErdvq4o).

Comment: @303 You question has multiple parts. I've answered one of them which is to give a workaround. There isn't anything wrong in answering the part of the question that you know the answer to.

Comment: Defaulting `T` with `U` is not the workaround I'm looking for, it also doesn't seem to compile on Clang 17.0.1. In any case, I've decided to limit my question to the non-compliancy part in regards to the C++20 standard.

Comment: @303 It compiles with latest clang version. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y61Eo9q1s). Also you're changing the requirements again and again. This is 2nd time you've changed the requirement(or added more) after an answer has been posted.